# Create a view in SQL, use it for dashboard creation in CRm

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Is it possible to create a view in SQL and use it to create a dashboard in CRM?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Just create the view in CRM instead.